# AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest returns content of local Python file instead of executing it

Tags: javascript, python, raspberry-pi, xmlhttprequest

Web page and Python script are both local in a Raspberry Pi (no internet connection).

The Python script runs fine when called from the command line.

JavaScript in the web page uses AJAX to call the Python script:

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        alert('readyState: '+ xmlhttp.readyState)     // Returns: 4
        alert('status: '+ xmlhttp.status)             // Returns: 0
        alert('statusText: '+ xmlhttp.statusText)     // Returns: (Blank)
        alert('responseText: '+ xmlhttp.responseText) // Returns contents of script
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "myscript.py", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send('test');
```

I also tried "GET" with the same results:

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        alert('readyState: '+ xmlhttp.readyState)     // Returns: 4
        alert('status: '+ xmlhttp.status)             // Returns: 0
        alert('statusText: '+ xmlhttp.statusText)     // Returns: (Blank)
        alert('responseText: '+ xmlhttp.responseText) // Returns contents of script
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "myscript.py", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

The script is not executed ( I can tell from the log).

Am I misunderstanding what AJAX can do? Can it not run local scripts?

My ultimate goal: to pass a user entry from the web page to the script, to configure the Raspberry Pi.

EDIT: Again, everything is local: no server, no internet, no HTTP.

If the answer is "no, you can't do that without a server" that's all I need to hear, and I'll look at using a port 80 instead to achieve what I want.

Comment: AJAX just sends HTTP requests.  You need to configure your server to handle that request the way you want.

Comment: It is possible to do this. But you cannot just execute arbitrary code on the server via http. You need a web server running on your server (raspberry-pi, in this case), and set up specific end points (urls). A common choice for this is to use a python web framework called [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). There are many guides and tutorials about using flask on a rasberry pi. Just google it.

Comment: @SLaks " You need to configure your server". There is no server. As I said, everything is local, no internet, no server.

Comment: @ Håken Lid "you cannot just execute arbitrary code on the server via http." That is not my intent: I use neither a server nor HTTP, and I do not plan to. If the answer is "you can't do that without also setting up a local web server", then that's what I need to hear.

Comment: @DavideAndrea: Then you can't do that;  Python is executed by a server.

Comment: @SLaks " Python is executed by a server" Well of course, that's not true: Python does not need a server to run: it can run in all sorts of situations without a server. "Then you can't do that"; OK, I accept it. Please post it as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python (in response to HTTP requests) is executed by a web server.

If you fetch from `file://` URLs, you will either get an error or raw content, depending on your browser.

You can run any HTTP server that can call Python scripts (using Python, or a CGI variant) on any port.